# Automatically rewrite UNC Path (using lmhosts if possible)

Tags: vpn, hosts-file

I have to VPN into a domain for work. On their internal network, paths are in the format of (for example) `work.local\shares\Share\SomeDirectory\SomeFile.ext`. When I utilize the VPN, however, I have to use something like `1.1.0.1\Share\SomeDirectory\SomeFile.ext`. Constantly copying/pasting then editing links is somewhat annoying, though not insurmountable. Ideally, I'd like to be able to redirect any paths from `work.local\shares` to `1.1.0.1`.

Using lmhosts, I was able to redirect `work.local` to `1.1.0.1`, however I can't seem to redirect `work.local\shares` to `1.1.0.1`.

Is this simply not supported, or is there a special syntax that needs to be used? If the former, is there an alternate solution?

Thanks!